# adding extra series on highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

am trying to add an extra series on highchart, using radio buttons.

this works, but when i select the radio button again it gives me another series, as i only want the data showing once..

my code:

```
 html
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <input class="test" name="g" type="radio" value="a"> A </input>
  <input class="test" name="g" type="radio" value="b"> B </input>
  <input class="test" name="g" type="radio" value="c"> C </input>
  <div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
```

code in javascript

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
                           type: 'column'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0]        
    }]
});

$(".test").change(function() {
               var value = this.getAttribute("value");


               if (value == 'a') 
               {
                   chart.series[0].setData([100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200]);
      ***tryin to add data here******* chart.series[1].setData([1000, 100, 370, 200, 900, 230]);****
                   chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: "kHw" });


               }

        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        color: '#08F',  
       data: [194.1, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]              
        });                                                 
              }

               else if (value == 'b') 
                {
                    chart.series[0].setData([100, 500, 300, 100, 100, 200]);
                    chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: "Raw" });
               }

               else if (value == 'c') 
                {
                   chart.series[0].setData([100, 300, 400, 200, 200, 100]);
               }

                else {
                   alert("Error!");   
    }
});
});
```

when i click on a(the radio button), it keeps adding series, when i only want to add it once. as you can see the *** here is where i am trying to add another series of data, but its not allowing me too.

this is confusing me:

```
  else if (value == 'c') {
                   if (chart.series.length >= 3)

                       chart.series[1].remove();

                   chart.addSeries({
                   data: [100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200] 
                   });
               }
```

what does this do

```
  if (chart.series.length >= 3)

  chart.series[1].remove();
```

my code keeps changing, once i click the radio buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refer the javascript code

```
    $(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
                           type: 'column'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0]        
    }]
});

$(".test").change(function() {
               var value = this.getAttribute("value");

               if (value == 'a') 
               {
                   chart.series[0].setData([100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200]);
                   chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: "kHw" });
        chart.series[0].remove();
        chart.addSeries({

        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        color: '#08F',  
       data: [194.1, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]              
        });                                                 
              }

               else if (value == 'b') 
                {
                    chart.series[0].setData([100, 500, 300, 100, 100, 200]);
                    chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: "Raw" });
             chart.series[0].remove();
        chart.addSeries({

        name: 'Rainfall2',
        type: 'column',
        color: '#08F',  
       data: [194.1, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]              
        });   }

               else if (value == 'c') 
                {  chart.series[0].remove();
        chart.addSeries({

        name: 'Rainfall3',
        type: 'column',
        color: '#08F',  
       data: [194.1, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]              
        }); 
                   chart.series[0].setData([100, 300, 400, 200, 200, 100]);
               }

                else {
                   alert("Error!");   
    }
});
});
```

refer the demo http://jsfiddle.net/Bhaarat/Qkzx6/2/

Comment: yeah i am using this, but i want to add another set of data for the value a

Comment: check code again, the one with the *** am trying to add new data here... as another series

Comment: Ok I got it.. and solved. I have updated code in my answer. refer http://jsfiddle.net/Bhaarat/Qkzx6/2/

Comment: when i click the radio button a, i want it to show 2 sets of series, but in my original code it was adding more than 1, but i wanted only 1 to be added not unlimited...

Comment: if you look at this, and you will see it keep adding series a everytime i click a
http://jsfiddle.net/Qkzx6/4/

Comment: yeah thats fine, but how come its showing in chart b and c, i just want it to show in chart a

Comment: yeah much better, can i just ask one last thing, because i dont really need the first series, so is it possible to have only a,b,c show when its clicked, and a to show when the page is loaded. because when i run some default data shows but i want it to be shown as a

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bhaarat/Qkzx6/7/ for Default value, you have to manage by code. bind same value which will come in option "a"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qkzx6/8/
how come when i click b, it shows 2 series, then c shows 2, then when i go back to b it just shows 1, when there suppose to show 2!

Comment: this is confusing me, if (chart.series.length >= 3) chart.series[1].remove(); i dont no when to add the numbers, the 3 and 1.